# Why my viewcontrollers are not being shown on scrollview controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have three step view controllers. I'm trying to display those three steps on a single viewcontroller (RegisterViewController) using a scroll view so that users can swipe through the steps.

I saw some other posts and got this far. When I run the app I'm getting a blank screen with the background color of the RegisterViewController. I wrote some println statements in the step view controllers to check whether they are being instantiated or not and I could see those statements' output on console. Please if anybody can help?

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  @IBOutlet weak var registerStepsPageControl: UIPageControl!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupScrollView()
  }

  func setupScrollView() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
    let stepOneViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegisterStepOne") as! RegisterStepOneViewController
    let stepTwoViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegisterStepTwo") as! RegisterStepTwoViewController
    let stepThreeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegisterStepThree") as! RegisterStepThreeViewController

    var stepViewControllers = [stepOneViewController, stepTwoViewController, stepThreeViewController]

    for index in 0..<stepViewControllers.count {
      self.addChildViewController(stepViewControllers[index])

      let originX: CGFloat = CGFloat(index) * CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame);
      stepViewControllers[index].view.frame = CGRectMake(originX, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
      stepViewControllers[index].view.frame.size = self.view.frame.size
      self.scrollView.addSubview(stepViewControllers[index].view)
      stepViewControllers[index].didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(stepViewControllers.count), self.view.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.registerStepsPageControl.numberOfPages = stepViewControllers.count
  }
}
```

**EDIT01:**
This code below works. It loads the images and they are being displayed as they are supposed to. But I don't know what might be the problem while loading views from other viewcontrollers.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tutorialStepsPageControl: UIPageControl!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var stepImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "tutorial_image_step1")!, UIImage(named: "tutorial_image_step2")!, UIImage(named: "tutorial_image_step3")!]


override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.tutorialStepsPageControl.numberOfPages = stepImages.count
  setupScrollView()
}

func setupScrollView() {
  var imageFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
  var imageView: UIImageView!

  for index in 0..<stepImages.count {
    imageFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
    imageFrame.size = self.view.frame.size

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: imageFrame)
    imageView.image = stepImages[index]
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
  }

  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(stepImages.count), self.view.frame.size.height)
  self.scrollView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: It could be that the frame sizes are wrong when you call this from `viewDidLoad`. Check the frame sizes in the debugger. Might be you need to run this code from `viewWillAppear` so the frames are set properly? Not the bug, but your line which sets the `frame.size` looks redundant to me as the value was already set on the previous line.

Comment: I remember that geometry has not yet been set in viewDidLoad, so try putting it in viewWillAppear

Comment: @EpicDefeater I don't think that's the case. I've added another code snippet which works just fine with imageviews instead of viewcontrollers.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Yes. That line is redundant, Thanks for reminding me to remove that. Frame sizes are being set right but views are not being added on them or something else is wrong which I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I deleted the step controllers and added them again from scratch. Did a clean build and now it's working. Don't know what was I doing wrong. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the line:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(stepViewControllers.count), self.view.frame.height)
```

Above this line:

```
for index in 0..<stepViewControllers.count {
```

This issue might be coming from the fact that you're adding the subviews before you sent the `contentSize`.

Comment: Nope! It doesn't affect anything. I've added another code snippet which works just fine with imageviews instead of viewcontrollers.